# Getting data from a text into an array

Tags: c, scanf

I've got homework, to take phone numbers from a text file, and put it into an array...
here is what I wrote, though it puts nothing on it...
the loop is that as long as theres text in the .txt files, read it into the array...

```
void get_phones(int *phones)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("phones.txt", "rt");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &phones) > 0)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &phones);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Show us at least part of your "phones.txt" file.  (I'm betting it is in a format that does not work with the way you wrote your code.)

Comment: 012-3456789
013-4318240
and it keep goes this way(every number has it's own line)...

Comment: Exactly what I thought.  Do those look like integers?   How do you expect `fscanf` to put that into "%d"?

Comment: I've changed it into 0123456789, in this way, those are ints, so I dont understand why %d is a problem now...

Comment: If you changed it to remove the dash (-), then it likely should work with %d.   If you're still having problems, describe EXACTLY what is going wrong now.

Comment: The only thing going wrong is that if I have for example 3 numbers, it only saves into the arr the last one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lastest update:**

For testing: 
please put the following code in your `main()`,and change the number 10 to the # of lines you have in the file. To compute the upper bound automatically you can try to change the return type of `get_phones` to `int` and put a counter in the while-loop.

```
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   printf("%lld\n",*(phones+i));
}
```

**You need deference a pointer in order to print the actual value. Otherwise you are printing the address stored in the pointer.** And `phones`, besides being the name of an array, it is **a pointer pointing to the first element in the array** in its nature. For more info on pointer and array, see [this tutorial](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch2x.htm).

**Assume that you are using a 32-bit machine**
The phone numbers I put in my textfile is the following:
22121222345
678139199
111111111

*Note that 22,121,222,345>=2,147,483,647,* which is the maximum number an int can represent. (For `unsigned int`  it is 2^32-1). Now if we try to run the following code:

```
void get_phones(int *phones){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("phones.txt", "rt");

    if (fp == NULL)
        printf ("Error\n");
    else
        while (fscanf(fp, "%d\n", phones++) !=EOF){}

}
```

The list of number printed on terminal are: 
646385865
678139199
111111111

 The first number saved in the array is totally random! Why? because it is too large for an integer and it overflows.

Now if we try the following version:

```
void get_phones(long long* phones){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("phones.txt", "rt");
        if (fp == NULL)
            printf ("Error\n");
        else
            while (fscanf(fp, "%lld\n", phones++) !=EOF){}

}
```

The list of number printed on terminal are:
22121222345
678139199
111111111

Why does it work? Because the type `long long` can store number up to 2^63-1 = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 

Tested working version. Change the data type to `long long` if you want.

!! The problem with your code is that you are passing the wrong thing to the `fscanf`. `phones` is already a pointer -- it is pointed to the starting point of the array. when you write `phone++`, it passes the current pointer to fscanf, and increase the pointer by one, which moves the pointer to the next slot in the integer array. 

Also, although `fscanf` will return the number of items it scanned, in your while loop condition, the scanning is already performed. So you don't need to call it second time in the body of the while loop

5195551234 this number is still too large for `unsigned long`, unfortunately. Because for 32-bit machine, both `int` and `unsigned long` has the max value $2^{32}-1$. Check out [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29) if you need more information on this. Instead you need `long long` if you are running your code on 32-bit machine, otherwise it will overflow and store incorrect data.

Comment: lol'd, according to your text file, it shouldn't be "%d\n". because you have ‘-’ and it is not a proper number. Can you also paste your main()? I am wondering if you declared it as an array.

Comment: @AmitM9S6 it should work properly now. Change the data type to long long if you want.

Comment: It doesnt, It only gives me 1 number right now into the arr, and even the number I get, isnt on the list of the phones...
you'v wrote %s in the fscanf, I dont understand why..

Comment: @AmitM9S6 ouch, change it to %d, my fault. Because you said you change it to the format 123456, so there was one version before that works for 123-4567. After I saw that you change the format to 123456, I edited my code here again. But I forgot to change %s to %d

Comment: Yeah, though even when it's %d, it doesnt work properly... it gives me a random number, that isnt from the txt file...

Comment: @AmitM9S6  
it shouldn't. only if you give it a number larger than 2^31-1. See my newly edited answer...

Comment: Now it gives me a huge number when I do 'printf("%lld\n", phones);', also, it;s a random number every time I run the program

Comment: @AmitM9S6 you are printing the wrong thing. see the latest update in the answer..

Comment: I'm suppost to print phones, because their supposts to be inside it.. no ?

Comment: @AmitM9S6 Could you please at least try to open the link to the tutorial in my answer? Understand the relationship between pointer and arrays is ESSENTIAL. And I think you don't really understand what pointers do. Anyway I've pasted every single char of my original code  http://pastebin.com/6bj1RHSL. and I am done explaining here, forever.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the other answers, you should be using `long unsigned` instead of `int` (I'm assuming the phone numbers are something like 5195551234 - this is too large for `int`).

If you know the max number of phone numbers in the file, you can pre-allocate space for the array like this:

```
long unsigned phones[1024];
```

where in this case I've assumed a max number of 1024. You can also allocate memory on the fly using `malloc` (see the man page for details) if you don't know the max number.

Your function `get_phones` should probably return the number of phone numbers you read as well (this ties back to the fact that the logic of your while loop is incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have `main()` function for make program to run (refer to docs)
2. `int *phones` should point to allocated memory.
3. `fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &phones);` -- each call of this function rewrites previously read number, e. g. each number after reading is put at the same memory address as the previous one.
4. This is not correct logic of behaviour to call fscanf twice a loop iteration.
   The result of first fscanf() is checked, but the result of the second is not.

Comment: so How can I solve 3? because now it only gives me the last number, insted of putting every number into the arr...
I've changed the calling to fscanf,it works propely now, but it only gets the last number

Comment: Chi has given the correct number: phones++ instead of  &phones